# Create backend user not working in Umbraco9 RC3

Tags: umbraco

I am trying to get external login with identityserver4 to work. It almost works, however, it does not auto-create or links when an external user is logged in. If I create a user in Umbraco am able to link the user manually.

I have the following configured - but I must be missing something

```
.AddBackOfficeExternalLogins(builder =>
                builder.AddBackOfficeLogin(
                    build =>

                       build.AddOpenIdConnect(
                               build.SchemeForBackOffice(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme),
                               "External login",
                               options =>
                               {
                                   // use cookies
                                   options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                                   // pass configured options along
                                   // Use the authorization code flow
                                   options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;

                                   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                                   options.Authority = "https://localhost:3930";
                                   options.MetadataAddress = "https://localhost:3930/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                                   options.ClientSecret = "**";
                                   options.ClientId = "***";
                                   options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                                   options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                                   options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/");
                                   options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/oidc-signout";
                                   options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "**";

                                   options.Scope.Clear();
                                   options.Scope.Add("openid");
                                   options.Scope.Add("profile");
                                   options.Scope.Add("email");
                                   options.SaveTokens = true;
                                   options.UsePkce = true;

                                   options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                                   {
                                       NameClaimType = "name",
                                       RoleClaimType = "role",

                                   };

                               }
                           ),
                   options =>
                           new BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions(

                               "btn-primary", // button stype
                               "fa-windows", // icon
                                new ExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(autoLinkExternalAccount: true, defaultUserGroups: new[] { Constants.Security.EditorGroupAlias }, defaultCulture: "en-US", allowManualLinking: true)
                                {
                                    OnAutoLinking = (user, loginInfo) =>
                                    {
                                        //
                                    },
                                    OnExternalLogin = (user, loginInfo) =>
                                    {
                                        return true;

                                    }
                                }, 

                               true, // deny local login
                               false, // autoredirect local login to external login
                               null) // custom backoffice view
                   )
               )
```